# Images not displayed in silverlight when app is run

Tags: visual-studio, silverlight, image

I'm trying to display an image within a Silverlight application but the image does not display when the application is run. When creating the project within Visual Studio I chose the "Automatically generate a test page to host Silverlight at build time" option.

Complete code as an example:

```
<UserControl x:Class="SilverlightApplication3.Page"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation" 
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml" 
    Width="400" Height="300">
    <StackPanel>        
        <Image Source="http://www.beachtownpress.com/db5/00415/beachtownpress.com/_uimages/beach7.jpg" />
    </StackPanel>
</UserControl>
```

The application appears perfectly within Visual Studio, but when I run the application, the image does not display. Any ideas?

Comment: Have you tried to load the image locally?

Comment: No, because I need to load images from URLs.

Comment: It seems like a simple thing, any ideas why the above code does not work?

Answer (score 1):

Mmm...

Take a look to this doc:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.image.source(VS.95).aspx

I think the main issue is that you are making a cross domain call, just and advice: download fiddler, there you will check if the server where you are requesting the data allows cross domain calls (just give a try, load an image from flckr and see what happens).

One solution, could be to use tunneling on the server side (a custom http hanlder on your domain, that grabs the image from a remote server and redirects it to your SL petition).

HTH
     Braulio

Answer (score 0):

Your example is absolutely working. I've just tried it.

May be the problem is in the network?

You can debug network communications via [Fiddler](http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/version.asp).

Answer (score 0):

While cross-domain URL access is allowed for the Image control, cross-scheme access is not. When running using the automatically generated test page, it will run from your local drive (I guess that would indirectly run in under the FILE protocol), so it will not be allowed to cross-scheme to the HTTP protocol. What you should do is to have the page containing your Silverlight control run under `http://localhost`, that should do the trick.

Reference: [URL Access Restrictions in Silverlight](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc189008%28VS.95%29.aspx)

Alternatively, at your Silverlight Project (not the web project) properties, at Debug pane, select to run it as OOB application for testing

Answer (score 0):

This is a real show stopper!!!.
At least webservice calls are still possible if you install some stupid file on the webserver of the webservice.  Maybe this helps: install a clientaccesspolicy.xml on the webserver for images.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc645032%28VS.95%29.aspx